# while mapping into _id of axios response Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

Tags: javascript, dictionary, axios

Problem with map function after axios fetch.
while mapping into _id of axios response Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        options: []
        
    }

  deleteOption = (optiontodelete) => {
        Axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/options/${optiontodelete}`, { headers: AuthHeader() })
        .then(res => {if(res.status === 200) 
            this.notifyMessage()
        }).then(
            this.setState({ 
            options: this.state.options.map((item) =>{
                optiontodelete !== item._id
            })
        })
        ).catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
        
        console.log(optiontodelete)
    }
```

This is the Error I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
// Function deleteOption is called with the argument of id (eg: 62e7563624811d383e390d1b)
```

What's wrong here ??

Comment: this.state.options is an empty array, where do you put data in that array. You are essentially looping at an empty array and hence it complains that there is no _id property.

Comment: It's not an empty array in the real application. I just want you guys to know that I'm using state, that's the reason here to use an empty array. In the real application I figured out the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe item is undefind?

```
console.log(item); // undefind
```

Comment: But console.log(this.state.options) 0: {_id: '62e76e0b24811d383e390de1', option: 'Hi', __v: 0}
1: {_id: '62e76e0f24811d383e390de3', option: 'Hi hey', __v: 0}